# How to share map with pushpins : Bing Maps, WP8.1, Map Control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

I'm working with MapControl from wp8.1 default controls. I can add different elements on map:

```
MapControl.MapElements.Add(polygonElement);
MapControl.MapElements.Add(mapIcon);
```

The question is, how to share this element to somebody? When I use Bing Maps browser app I can simply click on "share" button and get a link

http://binged.it/1zEKwlo

that will display all added data to anyone who has this link. Is there any way to share MapElements to another user?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. If you want to share a map view you could capture a screenshot and send that, but that wouldn't be very interactive and I'm guessing not what you want. If you only want to share point based data then you can create a link to the Bing Maps consumer site which would cause the native maps app on Windows Phone to open (opens in browser for other apps). This would allow you to share a single point. If you want to share anything more than that I would recommend creating a mobile website that either loads data from the URL string, or from a database. If you are only sharing a little bit of data a URL might be enough. If you have enough data to make a URL longer than 2083 characters then you will need to look at a different solution. One option is to create a web service for saving the map view. This could generate a unique ID for the view and then you could pass that ID to a custom mobile website as a parameter in the URL. This process requires a decent amount of development but would remove most limitations you will encounter using other approaches. If you use this method I recommend taking a look at the Azure mobile services as you can quickly and easily create a web service that is connected to a database. You can even add authentication easily as well if you wanted.

Comment: I know that Google Maps provide developers with ability to publish new maps, icons etc. So, Bing do not have such function, right?

Comment: Google did that through a website. Bing Maps does that as well through the Bing Maps consumer site. Use the "My Places" functionality. You can find some information about this here: http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/ff808584.aspx